# How can I disable Jest's unhandledRejection detection

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm writing a test and simulates a failure API response. The library that acts as a client for that API generates an uncaught rejection in this case.

This is 100% a bug in the library and we're on the process of deprecating that library, but migrating away from it will take some more weeks and I need my test passing today.

Unfortunately, Jest does not offer a functionality to disable this behavior. jest-circus adds its own handlers and fails the test. This happens in [jest-circus/src/globalErrorHandlers.ts](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/e0b33b74b5afd738edc183858b5c34053cfc26dd/packages/jest-circus/src/globalErrorHandlers.ts).

I've tried commenting-out the body of `uncaught` in that file and that does indeed "fix" my problem, which confirms these handlers are what I'm looking for.

```js
/**
 * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */
const uncaught = error => {
  // commenting-out this call to dispatchSync "fixes" the issue
  // (0, _state.dispatchSync)({
  //   error,
  //   name: 'error'
  // });
};
```

My next thought was to do a `process.removeAllListeners('unhandledRejection');` in my test (roughly speaking), but that doesn't work, even when running with `--runInBand`.

After some debugging, I found out that:

- `process.pid` in my test and `parentProcess.pid` in jest-circus are equal, but
- `process.listenerCount('unhandledRejection')` and `parentProcess.listenerCount('unhandledRejection')` are not (zero and one, respectively), and
- `process.mainModule` is `undefined` in my test but `parentProcess.mainModule` is defined in jest-circus (`filename: .../jest/bin/jest.js`).

That confused me completely. They seem to be different processes, yet share the same `pid`.

To debug further, I did a

```js
  // in my test
  beforeAll(() => {
    process.emitWarning('emitted warning process from my test. count: ' + process.listenerCount('unhandledRejection'));
  });

  // in globalErrorHandlers.js
  parentProcess.on('warning', warning => {
    console.log('parentProcess warning', parentProcess.listenerCount('unhandledRejection'), ' --- ', warning);
  });
```

And this outputs `parentProcess warning 1  ---  Warning: emitted warning process from my test. count: 0` to the console, which I guess would indicate they are the same process (which makes sense), yet somehow the `listenerCount` differs!

As a side note, jest-circus' `injectGlobalErrorHandlers` always runs *before* my test code, even global-space code. `restoreGlobalErrorHandlers` always runs *after*.

Answer (score 2):

It seems a custom Jest environment will do the trick:

```js
// no-unhandled-rejection-failures-environment.ts

import NodeEnvironment from 'jest-environment-node';
import { AsyncEvent } from '@jest/types/build/Circus';

export default class MyEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
  async handleTestEvent(event, state) {
    if (event.name === 'test_start') {
      process.removeAllListeners('unhandledRejection')
    }
  }
}

// in the test file

/**
 * @jest-environment ./tests/no-unhandled-rejection-failures-environment.ts
 */
```

Taken from [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10364#issuecomment-669047725) on a GitHub issue.